# Two questions:1. On Threads 2. On Socket

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android Programming...I have two questions

1.I am dealing with Threads now, I am bit confused with join() and wait() methods...let me tell my scenario,I have 4 thread A,B,C,D...i want run 3 threads concurrently (A,B,C)...after completion of A thread only my D thread has to start....how should i implement it ....using join() or wait() methods.

2.I am doing adb reverse.I want to send the data to my host system from my phone and i want to get the acknowledgement from host system. How should i implement this in programm..
adb reverse tcp:7000 tcp:7012

Please help me out...

Comment: You should post as two separate questions.

Comment: 1 Whats the problem with starting D thread when A completes? 2 I think adb is not intended for that, if you want to send data why dont you use a standard TCP connection?

Comment: hi nanoc, if i do like a.start();b.start();c.start();a.join();d.start(); then i will get the output as: after after completion of A thread only the remaining 3 threads are going to start..i don't know why its happening..